# copy file from one folder to another in gradle

Tags: java, gradle

[image]

I have to convert the ant project to gradle project. Here when i run the gradle build , it creates the war file and when it is deployed on server , the exploded war folder have two folder META-INF and WEB-INF , my requirement is 
**1. to copy the web.xml from config folder as seen  in image to WEB-INF Folder** 
and  **jsp folder as seen in image to Exploded folder**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [Gradle War Plugin docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html)

```
apply plugin: 'war'

....

war {
    from 'jsp' // adds a file-set to the root of the archive
    webXml = file('config/web.xml') // copies a file to WEB-INF/web.xml
}
```

Comment: hi idngzr , here my project doesn't have 'src/main'webap' , i have to copy it from context folder and i want to know how to refer that folder.

Comment: So you want to prepare the WEB-INF folder of the WAR before assembling it and deploying it to server. The war plugin can be configured like in the modified answer in order to do that.